# Display values of column 2 after column 1

Tags: sql

I have a table COUNTRIES.
I want a particular country to be displayed on the top and the rest of the countries to be displayed alphabetically.
For example my expectation is :

India -- to be displayed always on top
Afghanistan
Bulgaria
Canada
Denmark
Zambia

Comment: You need to add more details to your question.  For example, how is the "top" country determined?  What flavor of SQL are you working with?  And what does your query look like so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by putting conditional expressions in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when countryname = 'India' then 1 else 2 end),
         countryname
```

Comment: Beautifully done Gordon Linoff.  I would not have thought of that solution.

Comment: Thanks .. I actually have this query . Is there any other way to resolve it ? I am asking just out of curiosity.